# rmagick replacement with minimagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick, minimagick

at the beginning of the project i included RMagick gem and now app use it for getting HSL tone of image (for mono-color indexing/search). it works ok but in some reason i need to switch to minimagick but i don't know how to painlessly replace Rmagick's methods scale, pixel_color, to_HSL

my code now is:

```
image = Magick::Image.read(path_to_image) 
hsl_code = image.scale(1, 1).pixel_color(0, 0).to_HSL
```

i need something like:

```
hsl_code = image.minimagick_scale(1,1).minimagick_pixel_color(0,0).minimagick_to_HSL
```

Answer (score 1):

MiniMagick is a much more direct mapping to ImageMagick commands using [mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php).

You can look at [image magic <=> rmagick](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/optequiv.html) to see what are the equivalent commands.

For what you are trying to do this ould get you started.

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open(path_to_image)
scaled_image = image.scale('1x1')
```